# How to authorize the application in facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, post

I am developing an asp.net website and I want to post to facebook from my website so I created an application in facebook and I used below code but wher I run my website I get error

code :

```
private void Authorization()
    {
        string AppId = "1138658742823914";
        string AppSecret = "87471caa78f52e3919e43c3dc72b542a";
        string scope = "‎public_profile‎,user_friends";
        if (Request["code"]==null)
        {
            Response.Redirect(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect uri={1}&scope={2}",AppId,Request.Url.AbsoluteUri,scope));
        }
        else
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client id={0}&redirect uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}",AppId,Request.Url.AbsoluteUri,scope,Request["code"].ToString(),AppSecret);
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            using (HttpWebResponse response=request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();
                foreach (string  token in vals.Split('&'))
                {
                    // meh.aspx?token1=steve&token2=jack&....
                    tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                    token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));

                }
            }
            string access_token = tokens["access_token"];
            var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
            client.Post("/me/feed",new { message="Atefeh Ahmadi Hello every One"});

        }
```

error :

```
Facebook.FacebookOAuthException: (OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

[See Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Lw5r.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have not configured your app properly in facebook or you have not mentioned your website url correctly while creating an app on facebook.

Comment: I have done these you saied and I checked them for  some times .but I doent know why I get error . please help me more

Comment: The account by which you created the app and the account you are using to make posts are same?

Comment: Yes.they are the same

Comment: it can be permission issue,make sure proper scope is defined.

Comment: A user access token with publish_actions permission can be used to publish new posts.

Comment: after I used publish_actions permission I get another error The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request